# Why the button can't be clicked?

Tags: javascript

why when i put button and onclick event on function like the below code but the button can't be clicked? please explain me about that. Here is the source code:

```
var Stop = function(){
document.getElementById("scoring").innerHTML = "<div style='background-color: black; position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 37%; width: 30%; height: 50%; color: white; font-size: 32px; font-family: Courier;'>" + "YOUR SCORE: " + numberCoin + "<br>" + "<br>" + "<button type='button' width='50%' height='10%' onclick='playinstruction()'>RESTART</button>" + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Have you got a function called `playinstruction`? Can you show us the code for this function? Is it globally accessible?

Answer (score 4):

You're leaving the page when you set `document.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

The button should be made this way:

```
<button style='width: 50%; height :10%;' onclick='playinstruction()'>RESTART</button>
```

Some more changes I've made to make this work:
first I removed the href. I'm not sure why is it there, but first get the button to work before you decide it's the right thing to do.
Second, I declared the function like this and than called it:

```
function stop(){//Do something};
stop();
```

please notice declaring `var stop = function(){}` is not a bad thing to do. Just showing how i did it